# Why ViewControler's subView's frame got reset between viewWillAppear and DidAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I wonder why the subview's frame is reset between viewWillAppear and DidAppear? And how I can fix this problem. The whole code is on the pic.

[image]

Comment: You may have an issue with a default autoResize / autoLayout. What's the frame of `self.view` in both methods ?

Comment: @NerKatel normal viewcontroller without xib, i've tried setting those property of the base viewController, but it's not helpig.

Comment: Would you mind printing the frame in both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` using the following : `NSLog(@"Self : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));`

Comment: @Nerkatel added and they both print `Self : {{0, 20}, {320, 460}}`